# Validation for Windows Forms Apps with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, validation, nhibernate-validator

I've been using Nhibernate (with fluent nhibernate mapping) in a windows forms application and to do some validation and binding, I've been using NHibernate Validator too and when we try to validate some properties we take this error:

Could not load type 'NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException' from assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'.

Can someone help us ?

We don't know what is happening and looking some solution in web we found the nhibernate validator has a bug and we need to fix it or wait the next release, is that true?

Or if someone could recommend another good component to validate/binding on windows forms application with nhibernate, we really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of NHV are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHV-116) in the latest (1.3.1) version NHibernate Validator. You can

- fix it yourself (source are available). Might be relatively easy.
- use older version of NHibernate (3.1.0 for example should be compatible with your version of NHV).
- encapsulate validation in your domain objects, which in turn will make them real objects as oppose to simple data containers.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry, We got the sources and fixed it. :)

Comment: @Dmitry. Objects can have lots of interesting behavior in addition to validation (and of course data). Some validation behaviors depend more on external factors, like the current culture, than the nature of the object itself. Using NHV's ability to 'extend' the object in a separate assembly using a consistent validation philosophy is a home run and very proper OO, IMO.

Comment: This bug *is* relatively easy to fix which makes me wonder why it is still out there since May, 2011. Open source is open source, but I do wish NHV would get a little more love from its devs than it has in what is becoming a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the NHibernate version you're using. The NHV you're using is for NH 3.2.

Comment: I've been using the unique version that I found, version 1.3.1.4000, is there a version for nhibernate 3.2? where can I find it ?